# maven dependency not building when starting jboss server

Tags: java, maven, jar, jboss

I am using a certain imported dependency (org.apache.wicket) for two of my maven modules.

I'm getting following error when trying to start up the jboss server

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class etel.middleware.integration_feedback.IntegrationFeedbackReaderBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.etel.ear.etel-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [wildfly-server-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/ajax/json/JSONException
```

I see this error to mean that it can't find the jar for org.apache.wicket, however.
I have following maven dependcy set:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

what's weird is that this has previously worked with maven set like this, but doesn't anymore after running a clean install with maven.

I'm using jboss version 9.02 final, and using intellij as IDE

Comment: When you do a `mvn clean install` does the war file generated in the target folder contain the jar?

Comment: it indeed is in the in war, in the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use newest dependency, the one you use is quite old

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
<artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
<version>9.0.0-M3</version>
```

Comment: If the is issue known to be fixed in the newer version of `wicket-core`, this answer would be better if you included information about that (details about the issue, which version number addressed it, etc.). If instead you are making a suggestion that _might_ fix it, then this would be better as a comment directly under the OP's question.

Comment: I have previously tested, this and unfortunately I still get the class not found error